# C++ distributing program with dependencies

Tags: c++, compilation, dependencies, shared-libraries, clang

This is a very basic question regarding c++ program distribution. Suppose that I have the following program

```
#include "v8.h"
#include <SDL.h>


int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    // [AWSOME STUFF!]
    return 0;
}
```

It depends on Google's V8 and SDL2. On my Mac, I have installed those two libraries and I'm able to compile successfully the program like this:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/include -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers myprogram.cpp
```

To link the libraries, I can do like this:

```
clang++ -F/Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2 -lv8 myprogram.o -o program
```

If I understands it correcly, it work on my computer because the libraries are dynamically linked. What If I want to distribute it to other people that might not have them installed? How do I statically compile them to have hem included in the binary? Or how do I dynamically link them but distribute the library with the software?

Comment: You don't seem to be linking to the libraries at all. You only have the includes. Where do you make calls to the library functions?

Answer (score 1):

`-L` is used to specify library path

`-l` is used to specify the library name

If static libraries are available for the external components (Google's V8 and SDL2), then linking to it will embed them in the executable. Then distributing only the executable is sufficient.

If shared/dynamic libraries are used for linking, you will have to include the shared/dynamic libraries along with the distribution package.

Note: when distributing shared/dynamic libraries you have be careful of any additional dependencies and their versions.

Comment: I added to the question what I use to actually link the program once compiled: clang++ -F/Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2 -lv8 myprogram.o -o program